# Remove Downloads remaining and expires columns in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, download, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to reduce the table so it's just the download product title and the button to download the product. Here are the columns I want to remove "Downloads remaining" and "Expires" from Order received and My Account…
[Here is a screenshot](https://pasteboard.co/HZVWyoN.png).

To be able to only see the Product Name and Download Button

Comment: What have you done/tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following code that should remove "Downloads remaining" and "Downloads Expires" from everywhere *(even on email notifications)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_columns', 'custom_downloads_columns', 10, 1 ); // Orders and account
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_downloads_columns', 'custom_downloads_columns', 10, 1 ); // Email notifications
function custom_downloads_columns( $columns ){
    // Removing "Download expires" column
    if(isset($columns['download-expires']))
        unset($columns['download-expires']);

    // Removing "Download remaining" column
    if(isset($columns['download-remaining']))
        unset($columns['download-remaining']);

    return $columns;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Thanks so much for this code. Worked a treat. Even better that it hides it on the e-mails too. Thanks for allowing me to now move on with my life lol.

Comment: Semantically speaking, these should be `add_filter` instead of `add_action`. They both work of course. Just semantics.