# Customize WooCommerce Account downloads columns table

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, html-table

I have only one downloadable software in my website and it consists of several parts. This is the download page screenshot after the payment is done -

[image]

Since the same product name is repeating many times, I want to remove the Product name from Download section. Moreover, I want to rearrange the other columns and make the third column (**Download**) as the first column. **Downloads remaining** and **Expires** columns should appear second and third.

I followed the answer mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54559156/remove-downloads-remaining-and-expires-columns-in-woocommerce) and put the following code in my functions.php file -

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_columns', 'custom_downloads_columns', 10, 1 ); // Orders and account
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_downloads_columns', 'custom_downloads_columns', 10, 1 ); // Email notifications
function custom_downloads_columns( $columns ){
    // Removing "product_name" column
    if(isset($columns['product_name']))
        unset($columns['product_name']);
    return $columns;
}
```

But it's not helping, it's not making any change!

Can you please help me out?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some mistakes and missing things, try the following instead:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_columns', 'custom_downloads_columns', 10, 1 ); // Orders and account
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_downloads_columns', 'custom_downloads_columns', 10, 1 ); // Email notifications
function custom_downloads_columns( $columns ) {
    // Removing "Product" column
    if( isset($columns['download-product']) ) {
        unset($columns['download-product']);
    }
    // Moving "Downloads" column as the first column
    if( isset($columns['download-file']) ) {
        $download_file = $columns['download-file'];
        unset($columns['download-file']);
        $columns = array_merge( array('download-file' => $download_file), $columns);
    }    
    return $columns;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Comment: Dear @LoicTheAztec, thank you so much! I was going through the order-downloads.php file over here for a better understanding -https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.2.0/templates/order/order-downloads.php and in the mean time you have posted the answer. Thanks you so much :-)